# Как добавить поддержку JS в Links2 Links eLinks

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

Есть ли возможность добавить поддержку JS в один из указанных в заголовке браузеров? (Links2 - запускается в графическом режиме). Если есть такая возможность буду приветствовать любую информацию по этому вопросу.

Comment: Есть — исходники всех перечисленных браузеров открыты, исходники JS-движков вроде V8 или Duktape тоже имеются, скачивайте, соединяйте их вместе, за несколько месяцев может справитесь :)

Comment: Ну такой вариант я рассматривал в последнею очередь, я думал может там есть какой то уже готовый рецепт что бы собрать это все в единую кучу...

Comment: @СтасБорзых, это и есть готовый способ, иначе уже бы давно кто-то заслал в upstream. (Если сделаете, зашлите патчи авторам)